# C: fork with scanf

Tags: c, linux, fork, scanf

I tried this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(){

  int x=3;
  pid_t pid0=getpid();
  pid_t pid1=0;

  if(fork()==0){
    pid1=getpid();
  }

  if(getpid()==pid1){
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d",x);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

And `scanf` instruction is completely ignored. It just prints the old **x** which is **3**. Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: Since you've neither stated what is provided as the input on the terminal nor demonstrated that the `scanf()` succeeded by returning `1`, you're not in a position to complain very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mostly minor modification to your code.  It checks that `scanf()` works, calls `getpid()` a little less often, and reports things a bit more carefully.  Also, the parent waits for the child to exit before exiting itself.

Sample runs (I called the program `fork7`):

```
$ ./fork7 <<< ''
Parent (32976 - child 32977)
Child (32977)
Oops! 3
Child 32977: 0x0000
$ ./fork7 <<< 99
Parent (32978 - child 32979)
Child (32979)
Read: 99
Child 32979: 0x0000
$
```

Code (`fork7.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 3;
    pid_t pid1;

    if ((pid1 = fork()) == 0)
    {
        printf("Child (%d)\n", (int)getpid());
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)
            printf("Oops! %d\n", x);
        else
            printf("Read: %d\n", x);
    }
    else
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        printf("Parent (%d - child %d)\n", (int)getpid(), (int)pid1);
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("Child %d: 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why would you think it got ignored.

What exactly happens depends on what is used. Let's take a look at bash.

When in doubt, use strace (e.g. strace -fo meh bash + ./a.out)

```
24852 ioctl(255, TIOCSPGRP <unfinished ...>
24909 read(0,  <unfinished ...>
24852 <... ioctl resumed> , [24852])    = 0
24909 <... read resumed> 0xb774a000, 1024) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
24852 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [CHLD],  <unfinished ...>
24909 fstat64(1,  <unfinished ...>
24852 <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
24909 <... fstat64 resumed> {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
24852 ioctl(255, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS <unfinished ...>
24909 mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 <unfinished ...>
24852 <... ioctl resumed> , {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
24909 <... mmap2 resumed> )             = 0xb7749000
24852 ioctl(255, TIOCGWINSZ <unfinished ...>
24909 write(1, "[7]\n", 4 <unfinished ...>
```

24852 is obviously the shell. 255 is an fd associate with the terminal, the same one which is 0 in the process executing your program. As you can see here, an ioctl was issued to regain the control of the terminal and that resulted in *failing* the read operation. You would have learned about it if you actually checked the error.

There is a side note I modified the number and enclosed it within [] so that it cannot be confused with characters typed in.

Figuring out what happens with other shells (e.g. zsh) is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `scanf` will be getting failed. You can ensure this by doing this simple experiment, just check the return value of `scanf` in your code segment.

```
if(getpid() == pid1) {
    printf("return value of scanf %d\n",scanf("%d",&x));
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

Output you must be getting:

```
return value of scanf -1  //that means scanf got failed ?
3
```

*Now question is* **why `scanf` get failed** ?

Once the parent exits, the child gets adopted by a new parent (usually
the one with PID 1 I think - /etc/init or similar). And `stdin` control is also quenched. If you really want to get input(using `scanf`) in your child process, force your parent to wait till its child is returned successfully. This can be achieved as:

```
else {
   waitpid(-1,&status, WCONTINUED);
   return 0;
}
```

Please also make sure that your child should also return.
For more details about `waitpid` check [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/waitpid.htm)

**`NOTE`:**  It is always been recommended that you [not use](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) `scanf`. If you feel you must use `scanf`, you really should be checking the return value to determine if an input error occurred prior to the conversion. And please always check the return value of `fork` too.